# Countdown Timer To Display in separate views

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

Am using countdown timer in android app its working fine no problem in that
the countdown timer will be displayed like this in the textview 
60
59
58
and so on 
But here I want to display the seconds in seperate textview (e.g) 59 means 9 in textview1 and 5 in textview2 how to do this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: will there be two digits only or more than two digits too ?

Comment: in this app only two digits (i.e) SS only no HH:MM

Comment: `String second = SS.toString(); String firstCharacter = second.substring(0,1); String secondChararter = second.substring(1);`

Comment: % its fine how to display values in seperate textview e.g 60 means O in one textview and 6 in another

Comment: `textView1.setText ( firstCharacter ); textView2.setText ( secondCharacter );`

Comment: Have you looked at the [`String` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)? Documentation from Oracle and other sites should be your first port of call, *before* Stack Overflow. We are not a search engine for documentation. Google is. We are not documentation. Javadocs and tutorials are.

Comment: @user3251646 has your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are getting second value in some variable.

```
String seconds = SS.toString();
String firstChar = seconds.substring(0,1); 
String secondChar = seconds.substring(1); 

// Display in textview 
textView1.setText ( firstChar );
textView2.setText ( secondChar );
```